# How can we find whether default JavaScript file working on rails 2.3.8?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

how do I find whether default JavaScript file working or not?? Can same one give me small code example for this ??

Comment: Yes I try that It can easily done by putting alert("Test"); line into public\javascripts\application.js file. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ruby on Rails version 2, a quick way to find this out is to browse the source of your web page. The line where your javascript is, should end with a question mark and a number.

For instance, if you are using the default name `application.js`, open your webpage source and check if it looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/javascripts/application.js?1311166541
```

The `?1311166541` tells you that your javascript was found and it's loaded by the page.

If it's still not working, the problem is inside your javascript file and it has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails.

If you are using Rails 3, there will not be a number after the filename, but just before the .js. Something like `/assets/application-447c72e0609e769e6d9601ff3e930fdc.js`. The principle is the same.